# Can enumerate and see blob in storage account but cannot access it

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm working out of my local VS (2013 for one project, 2015 for the other.)
I'm new to blobs and security, I had to pick up someone else's project which had slow upload speeds because they were uploading from the client browser to blob storage, and then taking the blob, creating a media asset and encoding the asset as mp4. Well I'm trying to put the encoding and creation of the media asset into a background process.

When I run localhost, I can upload and save to blob storage without a problem. I can see the blob in the Azure Portal, and have even set the access type on the blob to container.  But when I try to retrieve the blob from background storage, it looks like I am getting a handle to the blob, but when I try to make a call to blob.FetchAttributes() I get a 404. I am using the correct storage connection string. There is a SAS token added to the URL (good for 1 year) and I have tried with and without the token.

I wrote this quick console app shown below, and when the blobs in the container are enumerated I see the blob that I uploaded, and that it has the correct size. Yet the call to blob.Exists() fails everytime. The redacted URL I am using for the fileName var to get the blob reference is being copied directly from the Azure portal. I have the correct credentials in my connection string, so I am not sure what is going on here. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
private static void ListBlobs()
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container=  blobClient.GetContainerReference("streamingfiles");

    // Loop over items within the container and output the length and URI.
    foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
            Console.WriteLine("Block blob of length {0}: {1}", blob.Properties.Length, blob.Uri);
        }
    }

    var fileName = "https://redacted.blob.core.windows.net/streamingfiles/47a49fb7-6f44-4f56-9695-37a4ddcd0f4a_56.mp4";//tried also with sas token
    var sourceCloudBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

    if (sourceCloudBlob.Exists())
        Console.WriteLine("Exists");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Does Not Exist"); //alwayd doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName).Exists();`
Set the `flatBlobListing` flag to `true`, since the blob structure are of flat hierarchy.

```
// Loop over items within the container and output the length and URI.
foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, true))
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

        if (blob != null)
        {
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            Console.WriteLine("Fetching Attributes");
            string blobFilePath = blob.Uri.AbsolutePath.ToString();

            if(String.compare(blobFilePath, filename, true) == 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Does Not Exist")
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Block blob of length {0}: {1}", blob.Properties.Length, blob.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. What's the point of passing the full path to the file when I already am in the container: 
   var fileName = "47a49fb7-6f44-4f56-9695-37a4ddcd0f4a_56.mp4";

Dev-One made me stop and think about it, but I can't mark that as correct.